# junit in eclipse null pointer exception MAC

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, junit

I am getting Null pointer exception while running Junit tests on Eclipse, Mac.This is my first run so don't know if I have to do something special for running tests on Mac OSX. I am able to run these tests on my Ubuntu VM,

```
Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.localURL(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.entryString(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.addEntry(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.localizeClasspath(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getClasspath(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looking at the source it appears to be failing to find a plugin. I can't find any bug reports for this.

Comment: Eclipse Mars for Mac OS X resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an configuration issue with my Eclipse copy. I have reinstalled the eclipse and this issue resolved