# Error: Eclipse 4.5 MARS NullPointerException (JUnit-Tests)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, nullpointerexception

I do have a problem with Eclipse 4.5 when building a JUnit Test Class.
I can build all tests with the help of ant in its repository.
I think it is a configuration problem in Eclipse.

I already followed a lot of solutions in this forum:

- Cleaning the path of eclipse itself
- restarting eclipse
- try to compile with JUnit3
- try to compile with JUnit4
- try another JRE
- start the project in a different workspace

The reason why I haven't updated my Eclipse is because my company only uses Eclipse 4.5. So I can't accept an answer to update it.

The error log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2019-09-09 17:55:58.495
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching JUnitEntityDBUtility".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.localURL(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.entryString(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.addEntry(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.localizeClasspath(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getClasspath(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Might be Eclipse bug [538433](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538433)

Comment: Have you tried to run a HelloWorld Junit class, from a new project made from the scratch? If it doesn't work, it must be surely a problem with the plafform. But if it does, you must find the differences between the failing experiment and the successing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delete and recreate your `JUnitEntityDBUtility` launch configuration**.

The stack trace can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31151214/6505250) and [here](https://github.com/eclipse/Xpect/issues/166). At the second finding you will find [the explanation and a workaround by Moritz Eysholdt](https://github.com/eclipse/Xpect/issues/164#issuecomment-75947056) for your issue as follows (highlighting by me):

> That NPE occurs if you execute a test's launch config in an Eclipse
>   that does not have the plugin org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime.patch
>   installed when the launch config was created by an Eclipse that did
>   actually have org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime.patch installed.
>
> Workaround: Install org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime.patch via the Xpect
>   update site **or delete+recreate your launch configuration**.
>
> [...]